# Как при копиляции сказать сборщику что бы он положил некие файлы в выходную папку с исполняемым файлом?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Есть консольное приложение **.Net Framework 4.6.1**. В папке с проектом лежат два файла, `appsettings.json` и `NLog.config`. Задача скопировать эти файлы в выходную папку(`/bin/Debug`) во время компиляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте эти файлы в решение (Solution) и в их свойствах укажите:

```
BuildAction: None
Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer
```

Comment: Лучше все-таки Copy if newer. Сборка будет быстрее, а эффект тот же.

Comment: Согласен, исправил.

Comment: Не понял в свойствах чего это надо указывать? Какой файл поправить?

Comment: В свойствах файла. Правый клик по файлу в Solution Explorer - Properties